# Spring Social Reddit Extension - OAuth 2 Access_token retrieval. 401 Error

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-social, resttemplate, reddit

I am trying to create an extension for [Reddit's Api](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2). Reddit follows OAuth 2 for obtaining an access_token. I am using springs RestTemplate to make all POST requests to Reddit. I am able to successfully complete the first stage according to the documentation. The user is redirected to Reddit where he/she allows my application, Reddit then redirects me back to my application with a code. However, the second stage doesn't seem to work. I must use that code to make another post request to :

https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token

Here is my attempt for obtaining an AccessGrant (SpringSocial wrapper for accesstoken sent back from Reddit). Spring Social requires you to extend OAuth2Template and implement the authentication process from there. In a typical spring application, a controller will use a helper to make a call to RedditOAuth2Template.exchangeForAccess and save the returned AccessGrant into a database.

According to the Reddit API Documentaiton a 401 response occurs due to a lack of client credentials via HTTP basic Auth. However, I am doing that in the createHeaders(String username, String password) method.

public class RedditOAuth2Template extends OAuth2Template {

```
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(RedditOAuth2Template.class);

private String client_id;
private String client_secret;

public RedditOAuth2Template(String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    super(clientId, clientSecret, RedditPaths.OAUTH_AUTH_URL, RedditPaths.OAUTH_TOKEN_URL);
    this.client_id = clientId;
    this.client_secret = clientSecret;
    setUseParametersForClientAuthentication(true);
}


@Override
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
protected AccessGrant postForAccessGrant(String accessTokenUrl, MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) {
    HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders(client_id, client_secret);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.set(accessTokenUrl, accessTokenUrl);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(parameters, headers);
    ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = getRestTemplate().exchange(accessTokenUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Map.class);
    Map<String, Object> responseMap = responseEntity.getBody();
    return extractAccessGrant(responseMap);
}

/*
 Reddit requires client_id and client_secret be 
 placed via HTTP basic Auth when retrieving the access_token
 */
private HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password) {
    String auth = username + ":" + password;
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
    headers.set("Authorization", authHeader);
    return headers;
}

private AccessGrant extractAccessGrant(Map<String, Object> result) {
    String accessToken = (String) result.get("access_token");
    String scope = (String) result.get("scope");
    String refreshToken = (String) result.get("refresh_token");
    // result.get("expires_in") may be an Integer, so cast it to Number first.  
    Number expiresInNumber = (Number) result.get("expires_in");
    Long expiresIn = (expiresInNumber == null) ? null : expiresInNumber.longValue();

    return createAccessGrant(accessToken, scope, refreshToken, expiresIn, result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 401 response for that endpoint, you're doing one of a small number of things wrong, all related to sending the client ID & secret as HTTP Basic Authorization:

- Not including a properly formatted Authorization header (i.e., `Authorization: basic <b64 encoded credentials>`)
- Not properly base 64 encoding your credentials
- Not including a client_id that for a valid OAuth2 client
- Not including a semicolon between the client ID and secret
- Not including the secret, or including the WRONG secret

You should check each stage of the Basic client auth, and log your output (or use a debugger to inspect it) at each stage to ensure you're not missing anything. You should also inspect the actual HTTP request you generate, and verify that the header is being sent (some HTTP libraries like to take liberties with headers)